# Link samba valid users to text file

Tags: linux, centos, users, samba

In my samba config - I would like it to link "valid users" in the example share below to the example text file:

```
security = user

[example share]
path = /example/path/here
read only = no
guest ok = no
valid users = (LINK TO TEXT FILE)
```

Validusers.txt

```
user1, user2, user3
```

Comment: No, you cannot do that, you could use a group instead and make the required users members of that group.

Comment: @RowlandPenny it seems I have an answer that does allow me to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you've asked, but there are three alternatives I'll describe here

1. Include a syntactically valid `smb.conf` snippet that defines your users.

   ```
    valid users = user1, user2, user3
   ```

   Include this snippet in your share definition. For example, if the snippet is called `/usr/local/etc/smb.valid_users.conf` you would declare your share like this

   ```
    [example share]
    path = /example/path/here
    read only = no
    guest ok = no
    include = /usr/local/etc/smb.valid_users.conf
   ```

   When you change the list of users you may need to restart samba (`systemctl restart smbd`). Notice that because this is an `include`, any valid code can be added - including entire shares that give away far more access than you would expect. Do not allow untrusted users access to change the configuration file!
2. Put the users into a group and reference the group in the share definition.

   ```
    valid users = @usersgroup
   ```

   Then exactly as usual you create the group `usersgroup` (see `groupadd` or `addgroup` depending on your OS variant) and add your users to it
3. Template the `smb.conf` and substitute into it as necessary. (The least favourite of my options.) Copy `smb.conf` to `smb.conf.template` and use this line in your share definition,

   ```
    valid users = %USERSLIST%
   ```

   Then use something like `sed` to substitute into the template

   ```
    sed 's/%USERSLIST%/user1, user2, user3/g' /etc/samba/smb.conf.template >/etc/samba/smb.conf
   ```

Comment: Loving option 1 thanks very much @roaima